# How to select from datetime in sqlite?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, sqlite, select

Joined is a datetime data type column in the database and dates are saved as '12/05/2010 15:54:32'
This my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE joined BETWEEN '12/05/2010 00:00:00' AND '12/05/2010 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

But it doesn't work. It returns no rows.

So how i gan get them?

---

Solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE joined BETWEEN '2010-05-05 00:00:00' AND '2010-05-12 23:59:59'
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: What's the first 59 in 59:59:59 represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that this is not an answer,
but perhaps it can help in narrowing down where the problem might lie.

**Edit:**
This also works at the shell:

```
sqlite> create table t (ts);
sqlite> insert into t values ('12/05/2010 15:54:32');
sqlite> SELECT * 
   ...> FROM t 
   ...> WHERE ts 
   ...> BETWEEN '12/05/2010 00:00:00' AND '12/05/2010 23:59:59';
12/05/2010 15:54:32
```

---

The following works for me in Python:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("CREATE TABLE t (ts)")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fe88ebbac90>
>>> conn.commit()
>>> c.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES ('12/05/2010 15:54:32');")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fe88ebbac90>
>>> conn.commit()
>>> c.execute("""
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE ts 
BETWEEN '12/05/2010 00:00:00' AND '12/05/2010 23:59:59'
""").fetchall()
[(u'12/05/2010 15:54:32',)]
```

Comment: Technically is what i'm using. I've tested qhe query in SQLite Administrator without results.

The joined field is a datetime and sqlite says that the datetimes should be saved as strings.

Comment: And ts is a 'text' or 'datetime' datatype?

Comment: @Sein: SQLite doesn't have a 'datetime' datatype.  Dates are stored as text.

Comment: Here's a reference:  http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity  In this case, I didn't use a type so it defaults to None.

Comment: I figured it. To retrieve results i must replace / with - and invert the date:

    SELECT * FROM users WHERE joined BETWEEN '2010-05-05 00:00:00' AND '2010-05-12 23:59:59' ORDER BY id ASC

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing dates as strings, you should use 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.  These will sort in chronological order, and have the added benefit of being accepted in SQLite's date and time functions.